# Компиляция под andoid

Tags: python-3.x, buildozer

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. В чем моя ошибка? Одно и тоже, на ОС Debian, Fedora и OpenSuse.
Пишет, что подробная информация в логах, а где эти логи искать то? Нигде никакой информации не нашел. Может поможет кто-то?

```
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/vadiki/ccc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/vadiki/ccc/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vadiki/ccc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/localhost.localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2024,unix/localhost.localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2024'
#     WINDOWID = '69206023'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     SDK_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/home/vadiki/.config/kdedefaults:/etc/xdg:/usr/etc/xdg'
#     LESS = '-M -I -R'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     JDK_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'cedilla'
#     MACHTYPE = 'x86_64-suse-linux'
#     G_BROKEN_FILENAMES = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = 'localhost.localdomain'
#     HISTSIZE = '1000'
#     LANGUAGE = 'ru:en_US'
#     FROM_HEADER = ''
#     MINICOM = '-c on'
#     JAVA_ROOT = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
#     JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
#     AUDIODRIVER = 'pulseaudio'
#     JRE_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
#     INPUT_METHOD = ''
#     CPU = 'x86_64'
#     SHELL_SESSION_ID = '9bbed99e6c5e410b905b56d2d0b63b35'
#     JAVA_BINDIR = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=local'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = '/usr/share/xsessions/default'
#     GTK_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc'
#     XCURSOR_SIZE = '24'
#     GPG_TTY = '/dev/pts/2'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'canberra-gtk-module'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/vadiki/ccc'
#     QEMU_AUDIO_DRV = 'pa'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     LOGNAME = 'vadiki'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     MANPATH = '/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1850'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/xauth_fUIoRE'
#     LS_OPTIONS = '-N --color=tty -T 0'
#     XKEYSYMDB = '/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB'
#     GTK2_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc-2.0'
#     XNLSPATH = '/usr/share/X11/nls'
#     HOME = '/home/vadiki'
#     SSH_ASKPASS = '/usr/libexec/ssh/ssh-askpass'
#     LANG = 'ru_UA.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=41;33;01:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.dll=01;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tbz=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.deb=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.lzma=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.zoo=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.tb2=00;31:*.tz2=00;31:*.tbz2=00;31:*.xz=00;31:*.avi=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.aiff=00;32:*.ape=00;32:*.au=00;32:*.flac=00;32:*.m4a=00;32:*.mid=00;32:*.mp3=00;32:*.mpc=00;32:*.ogg=00;32:*.voc=00;32:*.wav=00;32:*.wma=00;32:*.wv=00;32:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE = ':1.69'
#     PYTHONSTARTUP = '/etc/pythonstart'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION = '/Sessions/1'
#     PROFILEHOME = '/home/vadiki/ccc'
#     OSTYPE = 'linux'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     QT_IM_SWITCHER = 'imsw-multi'
#     LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR = 'no'
#     KONSOLE_VERSION = '210802'
#     XSESSION_IS_UP = 'yes'
#     KDE_SESSION_UID = '1000'
#     LESSCLOSE = 'lessclose.sh %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     G_FILENAME_ENCODING = '@locale,UTF-8,KOI8-R,CP1251'
#     HOST = 'localhost.localdomain'
#     XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME = 'localhost.localdomain'
#     LESSOPEN = 'lessopen.sh %s'
#     USER = 'vadiki'
#     COLORFGBG = '15;0'
#     KDE_SESSION_VERSION = '5'
#     MORE = '-sl'
#     CSHEDIT = 'emacs'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     WINDOWMANAGER = '/usr/bin/startplasma-x11'
#     PAGER = 'less'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     CVS_RSH = 'ssh'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     DEBUGINFOD_URLS = 'https://debuginfod.opensuse.org/'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     MANPATHISSET = 'yes'
#     XCURSOR_THEME = 'breeze_cursors'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share'
#     KDE_FULL_SESSION = 'true'
#     CONFIG_SITE = '/usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
#     PATH = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     PROFILEREAD = 'true'
#     KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE = '1'
#     MAIL = '/var/spool/mail/vadiki'
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     LESSKEY = '/usr/etc/lesskey.bin'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW = '/Windows/1'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: попробуйте ```My Appliaction``` заменить на ```MyApplication```

Comment: @DiHASTRO  Спасибо, но не помогло. Проблему решил за деньги

Comment: Мое решение проблемы:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340031/buildozer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82