# Скачивается старая версия gradle (сборка android приложения с помощью Buildozer)

Tags: android, gradle, buildozer

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Одно и тоже, на ОС Debian, Fedora и OpenSuse.
Приложение не собирается.

Вот сама ошибка:
(вырезал Listing так как он, как я понял не несет полезной информации и в нем нет ошибок. Оставил первую и последнюю строки)

```
vadiki@localhost:~/hhh> buildozer android debug
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Ensure build layout
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
    # Preparing build
    # Check requirements for android
    # Run 'dpkg --version'
    # Cwd None
    /bin/sh: line 1: dpkg: command not found
    # Search for Git (git)
    #  -> found at /usr/libexec/git/git
    # Search for Cython (cython)
    #  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
    # Search for Java compiler (javac)
    #  -> found at /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/bin/javac
    # Search for Java keytool (keytool)
    #  -> found at /usr/lib64/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17/bin/keytool
    # Install platform
    # Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
    # Cwd /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
    # Run 'git branch -vv'
    # Cwd /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    * master 4563f3e3 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2488 from misl6/release-2021.09.05
    # Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0\' \'toml\''
    # Cwd None
    # Apache ANT found at /home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
    # Android SDK found at /home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
    # Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19c
    # Android NDK found at /home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
    # Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
    # Check application requirements
    # Check garden requirements
    # Compile platform
    # Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
    # Cwd /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
    [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
    [INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
    [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
    [INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c
    [INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
    [INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
    [INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
    [INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
    [INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
    [INFO]:         myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, certifi), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
    [INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
    # Build the application #4
    # Copy application source from /home/vadiki/hhh
    # Create directory /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/app
    # Copy /home/vadiki/hhh/main.py
    # Package the application
    # project.properties updated
    # Gradle project detected, copy files /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/src/main/java
    # Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name \'My Application\' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
    # Cwd /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
    [INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 27
    [INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27)
    [INFO]:    Requested API target 27 is available, continuing.
    [INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
    [INFO]:    Found NDK version 19c
    [INFO]:    Getting NDK API version (i.e. minimum supported API) from user argument
    [INFO]:    ccache is missing, the build will not be optimized in the future.
    [INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9']
    [INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 4.9
    [INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
    [INFO]:         myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, certifi), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
    [INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
    [INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
    [INFO]:         myapp: min API 21, includes recipes (hostpython3, libffi, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, sqlite3, python3, sdl2, setuptools, six, pyjnius, android, kivy, certifi), built for archs (armeabi-v7a)
    [INFO]:    myapp has compatible recipes, using this one
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a
    Listing '/tmp/p4a-extra-env-6wcwrp45'...
    ...
    Listing '/home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local/bin'...
    [INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 31.0.0
    [DEBUG]:   -> running dos2unix /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew
    [DEBUG]:        dos2unix: преобразование файла /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew в формат Unix…
    [DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
    [DEBUG]:        
    [DEBUG]:        > Task :stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
    [DEBUG]:        Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        > Task :packageDebug FAILED
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        * What went wrong:
    [DEBUG]:        Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
    [DEBUG]:        > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
    [DEBUG]:           > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/vadiki/.android/debug.keystore": null
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        * Try:
    [DEBUG]:        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    [DEBUG]:        Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    [DEBUG]:        See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    [DEBUG]:   
    [DEBUG]:        BUILD FAILED in 2s
    [DEBUG]:        25 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 20 up-to-date
    [DEBUG]:        
    [DEBUG]:        
    [DEBUG]:        
    Exception in thread background thread for pid 32738:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
        fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
      File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
        handle_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
        return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/home/vadiki/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 
    
      RAN: /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug
    
      STDOUT:
    
    > Task :stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
    Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
    
    > Task :packageDebug FAILED
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
       > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/vadiki/.android/debug.keystore": null
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    BUILD FAILED in 2s
    25 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 20 up-to-date
    
    
    
    
    
    [INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 31):
            * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
       > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/vadiki/.android/debug.keystore": null
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    
    BUILD FAILED in 2s
    25 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 20 up-to-date
    
    [INFO]:    STDERR:
    
    [INFO]:    ENV:
    export SHELL='/bin/bash'
    export SESSION_MANAGER='local/localhost.localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2047,unix/localhost.localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2047'
    export WINDOWID='56623111'
    export COLORTERM='truecolor'
    export SDK_HOME='/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS='/home/vadiki/.config/kdedefaults:/etc/xdg:/usr/etc/xdg'
    export LESS='-M -I -R'
    export XDG_SESSION_PATH='/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
    export JDK_HOME='/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    export GTK_IM_MODULE='cedilla'
    export MACHTYPE='x86_64-suse-linux'
    export G_BROKEN_FILENAMES='1'
    export HISTSIZE='1000'
    export HOSTNAME='localhost.localdomain'
    export FROM_HEADER=''
    export LANGUAGE='ru:en_US'
    export MINICOM='-c on'
    export JAVA_ROOT='/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    export AUDIODRIVER='pulseaudio'
    export JRE_HOME='/usr/lib64/jvm/java/jre'
    export CPU='x86_64'
    export INPUT_METHOD=''
    export SHELL_SESSION_ID='c95588e57d984900aad431f1780b577a'
    export JAVA_BINDIR='/usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin'
    export XMODIFIERS='@im=local'
    export DESKTOP_SESSION='/usr/share/xsessions/default'
    export ANDROIDAPI='27'
    export GTK_RC_FILES='/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc'
    export XCURSOR_SIZE='24'
    export GPG_TTY='/dev/pts/1'
    export GTK_MODULES='canberra-gtk-module'
    export XDG_SEAT='seat0'
    export PWD='/home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android'
    export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV='pa'
    export PACKAGES_PATH='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/packages'
    export LOGNAME='vadiki'
    export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP='KDE'
    export XDG_SESSION_TYPE='x11'
    export MANPATH='/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man'
    export SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID='1837'
    export ANDROIDNDK='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    export _='/usr/bin/python'
    export XAUTHORITY='/run/user/1000/xauth_GejrNk'
    export LS_OPTIONS='-N --color=tty -T 0'
    export XKEYSYMDB='/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB'
    export GTK2_RC_FILES='/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc-2.0'
    export XNLSPATH='/usr/share/X11/nls'
    export HOME='/home/vadiki'
    export SSH_ASKPASS='/usr/libexec/ssh/ssh-askpass'
    export LANG='ru_UA.UTF-8'
    export LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=41;33;01:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.dll=01;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tbz=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.deb=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.lzma=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.zoo=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.tb2=00;31:*.tz2=00;31:*.tbz2=00;31:*.xz=00;31:*.avi=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.aiff=00;32:*.ape=00;32:*.au=00;32:*.flac=00;32:*.m4a=00;32:*.mid=00;32:*.mp3=00;32:*.mpc=00;32:*.ogg=00;32:*.voc=00;32:*.wav=00;32:*.wma=00;32:*.wv=00;32:'
    export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='KDE'
    export KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=':1.74'
    export PYTHONSTARTUP='/etc/pythonstart'
    export KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION='/Sessions/1'
    export PROFILEHOME='/home/vadiki/hhh'
    export OSTYPE='linux'
    export XDG_SEAT_PATH='/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
    export QT_IM_SWITCHER='imsw-multi'
    export LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR='no'
    export KONSOLE_VERSION='210802'
    export XSESSION_IS_UP='yes'
    export KDE_SESSION_UID='1000'
    export LESSCLOSE='lessclose.sh %s %s'
    export XDG_SESSION_CLASS='user'
    export TERM='xterm-256color'
    export G_FILENAME_ENCODING='@locale,UTF-8,KOI8-R,CP1251'
    export HOST='localhost.localdomain'
    export XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME='localhost.localdomain'
    export LESSOPEN='lessopen.sh %s'
    export USER='vadiki'
    export ANDROIDMINAPI='21'
    export COLORFGBG='15;0'
    export KDE_SESSION_VERSION='5'
    export MORE='-sl'
    export CSHEDIT='emacs'
    export DISPLAY=':0'
    export SHLVL='1'
    export WINDOWMANAGER='/usr/bin/startplasma-x11'
    export PAGER='less'
    export QT_IM_MODULE='xim'
    export CVS_RSH='ssh'
    export XDG_VTNR='7'
    export XDG_SESSION_ID='1'
    export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR='/run/user/1000'
    export DEBUGINFOD_URLS='https://debuginfod.opensuse.org/'
    export ANDROIDSDK='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR='0'
    export MANPATHISSET='yes'
    export XCURSOR_THEME='breeze_cursors'
    export XDG_DATA_DIRS='/usr/share'
    export KDE_FULL_SESSION='true'
    export CONFIG_SITE='/usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
    export PATH='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c:/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin:/home/vadiki/gradle/bin'
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
    export PROFILEREAD='true'
    export KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE='1'
    export MAIL='/var/spool/mail/vadiki'
    export HOSTTYPE='x86_64'
    export LESSKEY='/usr/etc/lesskey.bin'
    export KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW='/Windows/1'
    export ANDROID_NDK_HOME='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    export ANDROID_HOME='/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    
    [INFO]:    COMMAND:
    cd /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a && /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug
    
    [WARNING]: ERROR: /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!
    WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
    No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
    Applying Java source code patches...
    Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
    Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
    # Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vadiki/hhh/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/localhost.localdomain:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2047,unix/localhost.localdomain:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2047'
    #     WINDOWID = '56623111'
    #     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
    #     SDK_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    #     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/home/vadiki/.config/kdedefaults:/etc/xdg:/usr/etc/xdg'
    #     LESS = '-M -I -R'
    #     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
    #     JDK_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    #     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'cedilla'
    #     MACHTYPE = 'x86_64-suse-linux'
    #     G_BROKEN_FILENAMES = '1'
    #     HOSTNAME = 'localhost.localdomain'
    #     HISTSIZE = '1000'
    #     LANGUAGE = 'ru:en_US'
    #     FROM_HEADER = ''
    #     MINICOM = '-c on'
    #     JAVA_ROOT = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    #     JAVA_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java'
    #     AUDIODRIVER = 'pulseaudio'
    #     JRE_HOME = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java/jre'
    #     INPUT_METHOD = ''
    #     CPU = 'x86_64'
    #     SHELL_SESSION_ID = 'c95588e57d984900aad431f1780b577a'
    #     JAVA_BINDIR = '/usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin'
    #     XMODIFIERS = '@im=local'
    #     DESKTOP_SESSION = '/usr/share/xsessions/default'
    #     GTK_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc'
    #     XCURSOR_SIZE = '24'
    #     GPG_TTY = '/dev/pts/1'
    #     GTK_MODULES = 'canberra-gtk-module'
    #     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
    #     PWD = '/home/vadiki/hhh'
    #     QEMU_AUDIO_DRV = 'pa'
    #     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
    #     LOGNAME = 'vadiki'
    #     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
    #     MANPATH = '/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man'
    #     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1837'
    #     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/xauth_GejrNk'
    #     LS_OPTIONS = '-N --color=tty -T 0'
    #     XKEYSYMDB = '/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB'
    #     GTK2_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/vadiki/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/vadiki/.config/gtkrc-2.0'
    #     XNLSPATH = '/usr/share/X11/nls'
    #     HOME = '/home/vadiki'
    #     SSH_ASKPASS = '/usr/libexec/ssh/ssh-askpass'
    #     LANG = 'ru_UA.UTF-8'
    #     LS_COLORS = 'no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=41;33;01:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.dll=01;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tbz=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.deb=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.lzma=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.zoo=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.tb2=00;31:*.tz2=00;31:*.tbz2=00;31:*.xz=00;31:*.avi=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.aiff=00;32:*.ape=00;32:*.au=00;32:*.flac=00;32:*.m4a=00;32:*.mid=00;32:*.mp3=00;32:*.mpc=00;32:*.ogg=00;32:*.voc=00;32:*.wav=00;32:*.wma=00;32:*.wv=00;32:'
    #     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
    #     KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE = ':1.74'
    #     PYTHONSTARTUP = '/etc/pythonstart'
    #     KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION = '/Sessions/1'
    #     PROFILEHOME = '/home/vadiki/hhh'
    #     OSTYPE = 'linux'
    #     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
    #     QT_IM_SWITCHER = 'imsw-multi'
    #     LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR = 'no'
    #     KONSOLE_VERSION = '210802'
    #     XSESSION_IS_UP = 'yes'
    #     KDE_SESSION_UID = '1000'
    #     LESSCLOSE = 'lessclose.sh %s %s'
    #     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
    #     G_FILENAME_ENCODING = '@locale,UTF-8,KOI8-R,CP1251'
    #     HOST = 'localhost.localdomain'
    #     XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME = 'localhost.localdomain'
    #     LESSOPEN = 'lessopen.sh %s'
    #     USER = 'vadiki'
    #     COLORFGBG = '15;0'
    #     KDE_SESSION_VERSION = '5'
    #     MORE = '-sl'
    #     CSHEDIT = 'emacs'
    #     DISPLAY = ':0'
    #     SHLVL = '1'
    #     WINDOWMANAGER = '/usr/bin/startplasma-x11'
    #     PAGER = 'less'
    #     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
    #     CVS_RSH = 'ssh'
    #     XDG_VTNR = '7'
    #     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
    #     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
    #     DEBUGINFOD_URLS = 'https://debuginfod.opensuse.org/'
    #     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
    #     MANPATHISSET = 'yes'
    #     XCURSOR_THEME = 'breeze_cursors'
    #     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share'
    #     KDE_FULL_SESSION = 'true'
    #     CONFIG_SITE = '/usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
    #     PATH = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin:/home/vadiki/.local/bin:/home/vadiki/gradle/bin'
    #     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
    #     PROFILEREAD = 'true'
    #     KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE = '1'
    #     MAIL = '/var/spool/mail/vadiki'
    #     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
    #     LESSKEY = '/usr/etc/lesskey.bin'
    #     KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW = '/Windows/1'
    #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/packages'
    #     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    #     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/vadiki/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
    #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
    #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
    vadiki@localhost:~/hhh>
```

Comment: "Почему оно мне качает" А что за таинственное "оно"?)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov
команда buildozer android debug закачивает заново gradle шестой версии, хотя я установил седьмую
Но это не столь важно. Пусть качает что хочет лишь бы скомпилировало приложение, но оно этого не делает. Уже неделю пытаюсь решить проблему.

Comment: Просьба не предлагать решить проблему установкой windows

Comment: Насколько я знаю, разработка под андроид на питоне - в принципе не особо распространена. У меня, к сожалению, в этой области знаний почти нет. Удачи в поисках

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov спасибо! Мне необходимо кросплатформенное приложение сделать. А c++ и Kotlin я не знаю. И в дальнейшем придется работать со sphinx

Comment: Здесь только мои предположения, но проблема сборки как таковой кажется связана с этой ошибкой `com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/vadiki/.android/debug.keystore": null`. Суть в том, что любой apk файл должен быть подписан особым ключем. У Вас этого ключа нет. При работе с Android Studio она делает всё сама, а вот с питоном я хз как это решается((. Что касается версии градла, то там ниже есть строка говорящая, что в настройках проекта есть что-то несовместимое с 7.0, поэтому использована более старая версия

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov ключ создал заново, но это не решило проблему :-(
Теперь вывалилась ошибка формата:
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/vadiki/.android/debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
Буду разбираться. Спасибо огромное! Вы единственный, кто ответил за две недели! Пишите ответ - Выберу, как лучший

Comment: Мое решение проблемы:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340031/buildozer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82