# Buildozer failed to execute the last command

Tags: python, kivy, pycharm, buildozer

Делаю приложение на Kivy и пытаюсь сделать apk файл через buildozer. Вот код программы.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello, World!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

При выполнении команды `buildozer android debug deploy run` получаю ошибку. Лог и весь вывод прикрепляю.

```
  RAN: /home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py build_ext -v

  STDOUT:
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
running build_ext
building 'jnius' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius
/usr/bin/ccache /home/roman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC -I/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/home/roman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -I/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/include/python3.8 -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux -I/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Include -I/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build -c jnius/jnius.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/jnius/jnius.o
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'jnius/jnius.c'
clang: error: no input files
error: command '/usr/bin/ccache' failed with exit status 1


  STDERR:

[INFO]:    pyjnius first build failed (as expected)                                                                                                                  
[INFO]:    Running cython where appropriate
[INFO]:    Cythonize jnius/jnius.pyx
[INFO]:    -> running python3 -cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main()); ./jnius/jnius.pyx

           working: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'                                                                                                    Exception in thread background thread for pid 62718:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./jnius/jnius.pyx

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1276, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 725, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 580, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1059, in build_arch
    self.build_cython_components(arch)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1084, in build_cython_components
    self.cythonize_build(env=env)
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1132, in cythonize_build
    self.cythonize_file(env, build_dir, join(root, filename))
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1121, in cythonize_file
    shprint(python_command, "-c"
  File "/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 953, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/roman/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./jnius/jnius.pyx

  STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/roman-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1264,unix/roman-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1264'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     SNAP_REVISION = '256'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     SNAP_REAL_HOME = '/home/roman'
#     TERMINAL_EMULATOR = 'JetBrains-JediTerm'
#     SNAP_USER_COMMON = '/home/roman/snap/pycharm-community/common'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_NAME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     TERM_SESSION_ID = 'bf7bc3a8-51f2-42bc-a247-59acecc3ba2a'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY = ''
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1179'
#     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'roman'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID = 'gnome-shell/PyCharm Community Edition/1278-2-roman-VirtualBox_TIME1884139'
#     SNAP_CONTEXT = '0l-VTsWKYEpq3OjPBYgn5C31IbtyY73OsvMJYbvqZKj48toNVxve'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/roman'
#     USERNAME = 'roman'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LC_PAPER = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/venv'
#     SNAP_ARCH = 'amd64'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
#     SNAP_USER_DATA = '/home/roman/snap/pycharm-community/256'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '53797947f28f4d7d840b10513ef7ebe8'
#     MANAGERPID = '858'
#     SNAP_REEXEC = ''
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'roman'
#     SNAP = '/snap/pycharm-community/256'
#     SNAP_COMMON = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/common'
#     SNAP_VERSION = '2021.2.3'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void'
#     SNAP_COOKIE = '0l-VTsWKYEpq3OjPBYgn5C31IbtyY73OsvMJYbvqZKj48toNVxve'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SNAP_DATA = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/256'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     PS1 = ('(venv) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
#     LC_TIME = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     SNAP_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:31786'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/roman/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/roman/PycharmProjects/test/venv/bin:/home/roman/.local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '22788'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/home/roman/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/roman/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/roman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/roman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Если честно, понятия не имею что не так. Видел аналогичный вопрос здесь, однако, там проблема была сразу видна и она явно не та, что у меня. До этого была проблема с sdkmanager, но её вроде решил. Теперь это вылезает. Искренне прошу помощи. Установку пакетов делал по этому гайду: [buildozer не работает!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1340031/buildozer-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)
Пишет, мол, не знает что такое Cython, но я его устанавливал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если еще актуально, то вот решение проблемы - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir_35vdchNo&t=230s (начало с 3:28, конец на 4:33)